# How to remove white line from Google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a problem in polygons or I can say in shapes. As you can see in image that White lines are appearing inside the Maps. Showing some horizontal line & I have indicated it in the screen shot (link) with red arrow. I want to remove it. How can I fix it? I also upgraded the Google map version but it was not work for removing the grid line.

Image URL is given below:

http://paronsoft.net/map-img/google-map.png

Comment: Looks like a problem with CSS applying to the image tiles.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate of the other question... if you look at his screenshot you can see the zoom controls are artefact-ing as well. This usually works for me: `#map_canvas img { max-width: none !important; }` where `#max_canvas` is the container for the map.